# How to set a max value for IntegerItem

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

I want to set a max value for an  IntegerItem. If a user enters a large number, I want to return a validation error.

```
final IntegerItem qte = new IntegerItem("qte", "Qte");
```

If a user enters, for example, a number below 5, this is OK, but a large number should return a validation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmartGWT has validators pre-defined that you can use. The list of validators is listed [here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/validator/package-summary.html). In this case, you would benefit from the [IntegerRangeValidator](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/validator/IntegerRangeValidator.html).

```
IntegerRangeValidator integerRangeValidator = new IntegerRangeValidator();
integerRangeValidator.setMin(1);
integerRangeValidator.setMax(9999); // for example
populationField.setValidators(integerRangeValidator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [TextItem.setLength()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/TextItem.html#setLength%28java.lang.Integer%29) method to set the **maximum number of characters for this field**.

For example:

```
final IntegerItem qte = new IntegerItem("qte", "Qte");
qte.setLenght(4);//maximum value 9999
```

No need to validate user input because user can't enter a number greater than 9999.